# jQuery as @font-face initiator

Tags: jquery, html, css, font-face

I am building an offline system, so i have the fonts loaded locally. Also I am not using jQuery anywhere. So when i was checking the load times of the files, i noticed that the initiator for the font files is shown as jQuery.min.js. Where did that pop up from? Is that jQuery embedded in the font file? Also how does it actually work "behind the scenes"?

[image]

Comment: might be that you have some chrome extension which uses jquery and somehow affects these fonts...

Comment: Oh, I indeed seems to be the case. I disabled my extensions and reloaded the page in incognito, it now shows filename:~infinity. Seems like a really stupid question now.

Comment: well not really, these extensions are always injecting stuff... Anyway happy that it helps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as there is no jQuery in the network requests I assume the jQuery is a part of some Chrome extension which applies some fonts / intercepts your fonts calls.

To fix the problem try to disable all extensions you have and try to open the page again.

With the extensions disabled, the initiator reverts back to the original files

[image]

Comment: In my case it was uBlock Origin